# Equivalent of Tortoise SVN update in Tortoisegit?

Tags: tortoisegit

I know it's a beginner question but I don't want to mess things.

I was using Tortoise SVN so far when working with gitHub.

When I was working on my fork, and I wanted to update files from my fork, I would just pick update.

I'm far to be a professionnal of all those gitHub stuff. But now I just want to do the equivalent of it in Tortoise Git, and I'm afraid to click anything because I don't know most of the options yet.

**To summarize**: Equivalent of Tortoise SVN update with Tortoise Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update is actually `fetch` and `merge` (which can be done by `pull`).

`revert` would undo a committed snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is probably the revert option?
It will revert to what is on GitHub.